# Navigation Architecture Component - BottomNavigationView lock destination

Tags: android-navigationview

How can I lock a destination navigation when I need to check an user subscription?

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, args ->
 if(user_is_not_subscribed)) {
   // lock controller navigation and stay in this fragment
 } else {
   // continue to navigate to destination fragment
 }
}
```

Comment: any ideas to solve this problem??

Comment: Solved
If want to combine both sets of functionality together, you need to call navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this); after setupWithNavController and trigger the default behavior with NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected()